# How can I make my toolbar a gradient in colors.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, ui-design

How can I make my toolbar a gradient between `#11FFBD` and `#AAFFA9` in colors.xml? My code for a plain blue header is:

```
<color name="primary">#00BCD4</color>
<color name="primary_dark">#00838F</color>
<color name="primary_pressed">#0097A7</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create in your drawable folder : gradient_toolbar.xml like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
android:type="linear"
android:startColor="#11FFBD"
android:endColor="#AAFFA9"
android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

And in your toolbar declaration add the following :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

android:id="@id/toolbar"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_toolbar"

<!--your other attributes-->

/>
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Craig\Desktop\PapuhWalls-master\PapuhWalls-master\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:9:15: Error: The prefix "android" for attribute "android:id" associated with an element type "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" is not bound.

Comment: you're putting your toolbar in a seperate xml file?